# Is there any relation between index of matrix $AB$ and matrices $ A$, and $B$?

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

The index of a matrix $A$ is the smallest nonnegative integer $k$ such that $\operatorname{rank}(A^{k+1})=\operatorname{rank}(A^k)$.

Now I want to know: what relation is there between $\operatorname{Index}(AB)$ and $\operatorname{Index}(A)$, $\operatorname{Index}(B)$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to the [Wolfram Language or Mathematica](http://wri.com).

Comment: Did you mean to ask this on [math.SE]?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The definition from that link doesn't appear to be the same usage of "index" as in the OP; by the definition from that link, every square matrix has index $0$.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not true. Consider matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}1& 0\\  0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A'=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\  0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, the index of $A$ is one and the index of $A'$ is 2. You are right if the matrices are nonsingular.